# Variable in Macros

Tags: c, macros

I am writing a program in c language. So, suppose I have defined a macro in c as follows :

```
#define TEST_MACRO(type, name) \
{ \

    int testVar = 0; \
}

#define TEST_MACRO_TWO(type, name) \
{ \


}
```

How can I use the testVar variable from the first macro in the second macro?

Comment: Considering that the variable is defined in its own scope, you can't. What is the *real* problem you need to solve? Why do you want these two macros? How will you use them?

Comment: If I had " testVar = 1; " in the second macro, why does that produce an error considering the fact that the testVar variable will be present before the statement when the text is replaced in main()

Comment: what is the problem.?

Comment: It seems you need to take a few steps back, and re-read your text book about *scoping* and variable life-time.

Comment: Consider you don't need to use braces in macros. Without braces, a macro can declare a variable to be used somewhere else.

Comment: How would you declare a variable that can replace a text in main() without braces?

Comment: #define TEST(blah) int testvar = 0

Comment: macro are just a name given to piece of code. Wherever you use this name, the piece of code tied to it is embedded right there. This is also why they are pre-processed.

Comment: With GCC you can take a look at the preprocessed code with the option `-E`. Then you're able to review the result of your macros.

Comment: I did, and it looks like it is printing an extra { at the beginning and extra }; at the end. Any ideas why?